# Javascript function not working, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning javascript, now I'm trying to do mini-coding challenges. I cannot figure out what needs to change:

```
let roll = function() {
  let roll1;
  let roll2;

  roll1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  return roll1;

  roll2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  return roll2;

  document.getElementById('dice').innerHTML = roll1 + "and " + roll2;
}
```

Comment: `return` terminates the function. No line after your first return will ever be executed.

Comment: Why are you telling this is not working? What are you expecting as result? Please edit your question and include that information so we can understand your problem and help you. Also, have a look at this link before ask and reply questions -> https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This is supposed to be for a Roll a Dice

Comment: @CentV I understand the urge to see what you learn in practice, but I recommend to continue learning a bit further. These are really basic principles of JavaScript (or programming in general) and not really a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also please don't fix the code in the question if you have the answer. Questions are for the community as a whole and fixing it makes it useless for other users as it becomes unclear what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `roll` is returning your roll1 and roll2 before it gets to update the html. Upon being executed `return roll1` exits the function and returns the value of role1. The lines of code after it never get called. What you need to do is just remove the returns from the function. when `getElementById()` is called that will, in a way, act as you returning the variables because it will update the html to display your result.

```
let roll = function() {
  let roll1;
  let roll2;

  roll1 = parseInt(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  roll2 = parseInt(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

  document.getElementById('dice').innerHTML = roll1 + "and " + roll2;
}
```